# Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" - plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

After executing it shows:

Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY TEMP_PACKAGE

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
begin end function pragma procedure
Line: 17

```
create or replace package body TEMP_PACKAGE is

procedure insert_temp
(aaCode number,aaName varchar2, aaAddress varchar2, 
 aaPhone varchar2, aaState varchar2 ) 

 is
 begin
 INSERT INTO temp_employee_azizbek
 (code, aadName, aadAddress, aadPhone, aadState )
 VALUES (aaCode, aaName,aaAddress,aaPhone,aaState);

 end;
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: you are missing one `end`. Add one to the end of the script. you only have 1 for your procedure, but not for the whole package

Comment: Thank you, after adding extra end it compiled successfully !

Comment: If you format the code neatly with consistent indentation and use the extended `end` syntax (`end insert_temp;` `end temp_package;`) this type of error becomes harder to miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an extra `end` is missing, and you need package `definition` (`header`) besides package `body` :

```
create or replace package TEMP_PACKAGE is
 procedure insert_temp(aaCode number,aaName varchar2, aaAddress varchar2, 
                       aaPhone varchar2, aaState varchar2 );
end TEMP_PACKAGE;
/
create or replace package body TEMP_PACKAGE is

procedure insert_temp(aaCode number,aaName varchar2, aaAddress varchar2, 
                      aaPhone varchar2, aaState varchar2 ) is
begin
 INSERT INTO temp_employee_azizbek
 (code, aadName, aadAddress, aadPhone, aadState )
 VALUES (aaCode, aaName,aaAddress,aaPhone,aaState);
end;
end TEMP_PACKAGE;
/
```